# path to root in asp.net for txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file

`file.txt` in the root of my asp.net project.

I am trying to read it from c#. I tried this

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader("file.txt");
```

I got file not found.

then I tried this

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader("/file.txt");
```

but I also got file not found

help please.

#### note

the file absolutely exits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StreamReader` does not use the path from the website perspective, but from the local file system perspective.

Try this instead, which converts the path to an absolute local path...

```
string localFile = Server.MapPath("~/file.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(localFile);
```

---

To give you a bit more understanding, the `StreamReader` is a .NET class (rather than an ASP.NET) class, therefore it doesn't understand anything about how your website is setup.  It needs to have a file path within the local server directory structure.

When ASP.NET runs, it's using a working directory deep within the system directory structure (I'm not 100% sure, but something along the lines of `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\`)

So what you were asking for is a text file in (for example) `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\file.txt`.